# sed + remove spaces between different char with "," seperator between them

Tags: sed

param can be one
 of the following

a,b   ,   f,     d

or

a, b     , c,    e

or

r , q  ,c , d

but we want a,b,c,d without spaces

for example if we get: a , b ,c,d
need to change it to a,b,c,d
sytax to do that
yael

what the best sed syntax to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
tr -d ' ' < inputfile
```

or

```
sed 's/ //g' inputfile
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
s/ *, */,/g
```

I haven't tested it so you may need to fiddle a bit.